# Does macOS need antivirus protection?

Tags: macos, malware, anti-virus

Are Mac systems immune to viruses and malware?

Do I need to install software to protect macOS just like we do for Windows?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380447/my-mac-is-opening-new-tabs-with-different-ad-sites/380458#380458

Comment: Nice write-up @ankii - that's Shlayer, btw, same as my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most, but not all, Mac virus protection is there to stop Windows viruses being spread further.

That doesn't mean Macs are immune - there are viruses/trojans/malware targeted specifically at Mac users.

[Shlayer](https://securelist.com/shlayer-for-macos/95724/) is a recent example, but not the ony one - check the table on the linked page.

There are also fly-by attacks & social engineering/phishing attacks that you always need to be aware of. Shlayer's attack vector is usually a simple "Your Flash Player is out of date! Click to update." Click to download, click to install & you just invited it in.

*After comments…*
There is no single authority on which antivirus is best, but there are sites which test [for a fee] various competitors in this field. If you just Google it yourself, you will get a thousand hits pretending to be advice, but actually just sock-puppets selling their own 'solution' with no authority but their own.

The only authority I know to be 'trusted' is [AV-TEST](https://www.av-test.org/en/) who keep tables of current antivirus products by OS, for business & home users. The most current Mac page is always at https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-macos/.

Comment: Can you suggest some good protection softwares for Mac ?

Comment: Antivirus test site added to answer.